# Printing within a class method in python does not work

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying to learn how to add support to a new website in youtube dl from [this website](https://filippo.io/add-support-for-a-new-video-site-to-youtube-dl/)
I modified it because the website is outdated. The following is my code

```
from .common import InfoExtractor

class VineIE(InfoExtractor):
    _VALID_URL = r'(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?vine\.co/v/(?P<id>\w+)'

    def _real_extract(self, url):
        video_id = self._match_id(url)
        webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)
        print(webpage)
        return []
```

My intention is to debug and print variables and see what is happening. So I try running it

```
python -m youtube_dl vine.co/v/b9KOOWX7HUx
```

However, I do not get the webpage variable in the console. What I get instead is?

```
[generic] b9KOOWX7HUx: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] b9KOOWX7HUx: Downloading webpage
[generic] b9KOOWX7HUx: Extracting information
ERROR: Unsupported URL: http://www.vine.co/v/b9KOOWX7HUx
```

Why does not the print function work?

Comment: Is an instance of `VineIE` being created? Is `_real_extract` being called?

Comment: @thedouglenz I edited the code, to include the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youtube-dl already has a [`VineIE`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/vine.py#L15). You should edit that extractor instead of writing a new one.

In any case, your code is most likely not executed. In [`extractors.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/extractors.py), import it, by adding a line like

```
from vine import VineIE
```

Again, note that your actual extractor cannot be called `VineIE`, because such an extractor exists already.

For more information on how to create an extractor, please follow the [**official documentation on how to create a youtube-dl extractor**](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#adding-support-for-a-new-site).

Answer (score -1):

```
webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)
```

seems to fail, can you post that function?

Comment: youtube-dl outputs which extractor it picks. Note that the output plainly says that the no extractor matched. Therefore, the code of the OP was never executed in the first place.